# Coinbase API: Where can I find the CB_VERSION date?

Tags: coinbase-api, api-versioning

My responses from the coinbase v2 api at https://api.coinbase.com/v2 always return:

```
"warnings": [
    {
      "id": "missing_version",
      "message": "Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) as CB-VERSION header",
      "url": "https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning"
    }
  ]
```

The documentation provides no date for the current api version. Where am I supposed to get this?

Answer (score 0):

The version given in the [api docs](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#versioning) is available

```
CB-VERSION:  2015-04-08'
```